# How to communicate from JavaScript to filesystem

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I am making a Windows application in Visual Studio 2010 by embeding a webbrowser object loading a local file.

Now I want the web page to read and write from and to the filesystem from JavaScript.

I have done the same in a HTA just calling simple VBS functions for read and write files.

How do I do in .NET 4.0?

Comment: Well, if you read the documentation it will indicate how to pass data from the application to embedded browser and vice versa.

Comment: Brilliant "answer". Forget Stackoverflow, read the documentation or buy a book at Amazon. Thanks, that's enrouraging :-)

Comment: We aren’t here to do your work, only help specific issues.  Which you didn’t demonstrate or provide a way to replicate your issue, thus the lack of help.

Comment: Describe what you’ve already tried and the results of any research. (You have searched for a solution to your problem before asking it, haven’t you? Stack Overflow isn’t meant to replace basic search skills.) Time can be saved if you can point out differences between your situation and other common ones. It’s even worth referring to other related questions explicitly – particularly if they’re on the same forum. Aside from anything else, this shows a certain amount of “due diligence” – people are generally more willing to help you if can show you’ve already put some effort in.

Comment: @Greg, Stackoverflow is mostly used to ask very simple question. If you ask a bit complex questions ppl easily get angry. Of course there are other ways to get information, but Stackoverflow is very useful, except ppl here alway tell others they are stupid idiots. Just answer and you get your most wanted points :-)

Comment: However, I did exactly explain what I tried already making a HTA. The solution is actually very similar. HTA and .NET are very much in family. Only a few changes was necessary to make it work the same way in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

You can fill data using provided methods.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myTextbox").SetAttribute("value") = "my_value" ;
```

and it is also possible to `Invoke` javascript functions as well. So that is how you can do it.